# Image of geometrical figures by linear application

Tags: linear-algebra

When the application is a rotation, symetry, projection, it is easy to find without any calculus the image of figures such as squares, circles, and so on. But how do you find these images when the application is not 'geometrically obvious'?

For example consider the application $f(x,y):{R^2}\rightarrow{R^2}:(x,y)\rightarrow(2x+y,x+3y)$, then what is the image of the square of summits $(\pm1,\pm1)$? And the image of the circle $x^2+y^2=1$?

Comment: Is it ok to find the images of (+-1,+-1) and connect these dots to find the image of the square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the square: a linear map takes parallel lines to parallel lines, so the image of a square is a parallelogram.  You can easily find the coordinates of its vertices.

For the unit circle: the circle can be written as
$$\def\x{{\bf x}}\x^T\x=1\ ,$$
where
$$\x=\pmatrix{x\cr y\cr}\ .$$
Its image will be
$$(A\x)^T(A\x)=1\ ,$$
where
$$A=\pmatrix{2&1\cr1&3\cr}\ .$$
If my calculations are correct (please check) this simplifies to
$$\x^T\pmatrix{5&5\cr5&10\cr}\x=1\ ,$$
and the matrix has positive eigenvalues so this is an ellipse.